# iPhone - NSUndoManager + NSInvocation + object released = crash

Tags: iphone, nsundomanager

I am building a undo/redo functionality for my app. I am using the NSInvocation method of NSUndoManager.

This is how I build the invocation

```
NSNumber *firstState = [NSNumber numberWithInt:fsNumber];
NSInvocation *initialState = [self restoreStateInvocation:firstState];
// ... the code continues...
```

these are the methods relates

```
- (NSInvocation *) restoreStateInvocation:(NSNumber*)number {
  NSMethodSignature *executeMethodSignature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:
                                                 @selector(makeUNDO:)];
  NSInvocation *moveInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: executeMethodSignature];
  [moveInvocation setTarget:self];
  [moveInvocation setSelector:@selector(makeUNDO:)];

  [moveInvocation setArgument:&number atIndex:2];
  return moveInvocation;
}


- (void) makeUNDO:(NSNumber*)number {

  int num = (int)[number intValue];
  // code crashes at this line... number appears to be deallocated at this time
  //
...
}
```

when the UNDO/REDO calls initialState the app crashes on the first line of makeUNDO, as pointed on the code.

how can I retain number without leaking?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct answer is to add the following line to restoreStateInvocation...

```
[moveInvocation retainArguments];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could retain `NSNumber` object because it's inherited from `NSObject`.

```
NSNumber* myNumber = [number retain];
```

you also need to `release` once you finished using **myNumber**.

`[myNumber release]`.

**EDITED:**

Use the approach described below...

you could have **myNumber** as your class member.

**in .h**

```
   @interface myClass {
     NSNumber* myNumber;
     }
     ............
     ............
     @property(nonautomic,retain)  NSNumber* myNumber;

     @end
```

**In implementation file (.m file).**

```
@implementation myClass 
@synthesize myNumber;

-(void) dealloc{

   if(myNumber)
   {
       [myNumber release];
       myNumber  = nil ;
   }
}

- (void) makeUNDO:(NSNumber*)number {

  self.myNumber  = nil;
  self.myNumber  = number;


  int num = (int)[self.myNumberintValue];
  NSLog(@"My Number -->%d", num )

  //
  ...
}
```